# Relationship between $A$ is normal ans $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning matrix analysis, and one theorem states

> A matrix A $\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is unitarily similar to a diagonal matrix if and only if $A$ is normal ($AA^H=A^HA$)

However, from the previous study I learnt that $A \in  \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is diagonalizable when it has $n$ independent eigenvectors. So it **seems** that the two claims are equivalent. But I do not know why this random thought is true or not

Could anyone help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: The key is the word "unitarily". Diagonalisable means that $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal for some invertible $P$, i.e. $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix. Normal matrices are unitarily similar to diagonal matrices, which means that $P$ must additionally be unitary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: ponder on the difference between the following:

$A \in  \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is diagonalizable - this means that there exists a basis of your space consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

$A \in  \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is unitarily diagonalizable - this means that there exists a basis of your space consisting of mutually orthogonal eigenvectors of $A$.